# Some Classes are missing in Google Places API Framework folder iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

I Follow these steps for install Google Map Framework:

[image: fig1]

And am unable to find the specified files in my Project folder:

[image: fig2]

Please tell me: from where do I find those missing files mentioned in the guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating your pod file?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en#upgrade_from_an_earlier_version

Just run pod update.

Comment: Thanks Bro , I just uninstall all pod related folder manually then install it again its work fine now and all files are shown over there , strange!!  but working :)

I think update will gonna work as well !!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link in order to work on Google Map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en

After downloading its library, link the library by following the instructions from this link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: I already followed same instruction. All project is working fine Just unable to work on those files which are unavailable or missed in framework